# Setting-up third-party VPN provider on Windows 10

Tags: networking, vpn

I have been using the built-in Windows 10 VPN function to connect to my workplace via PTTP. Unfortunately, the VPN functionalities on Windows are limited,  I am unable to see the status of the VPN in the taskbar making difficult to know whether the VPN is connected or disconnected!

Can you recommend any third party app that I can install on Windows 10, allowing to set-up the VPN with my own credentials and view the status of the VPN easily? Such as by showing a status icon or similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can download vpn from here:https://www.betternet.co/

To check it's status, you just need to drag out the icon from Show hidden icons in the taskbar.